# Why is my Yongnuo RF-600TX not working with my YN-560 IV?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-flash

I've just bought a Yongnuo RF-600TX transmitter but it looks like it doesn't work with my YN-560 IV flash. Does anyone know how to set up these things?

Comment: How have you tried to set them up and what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RF-600TX is a Yongnuo **RF-602** transmitter (just without the PC input port on top).

The YN-560 IV defaults to using the RF-60**3** communication protocol, which is different. You have to set it to use the 602 communication protocol if you want to remotely fire your flash from an RF-600TX transmitter.

[The manual](http://yongnuo.com.cn/usermanual/pdf/YN560IVy.pdf) says that this is an "Advanced Options Setting". To access it:

1. Press the **[Illumination/Sound]** and **[MODE]** buttons at the same time to enter the menu for setting the options.
2. Press the **[UP]** or **[DOWN]** buttons until you are on the **rF** setting.
3. Press the **[RIGHT]** or **[LEFT]** button to [change the setting from **60 3** to **60 2**](http://flashhavoc.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/YN560_III_RF_602_3_a400.gif).

There aren't instructions in the manual for getting out of the menu, but I'd assume hitting the [SET] button in the middle of the four-way buttons would do it.

After you've done that, so long as the flash is in radio slave mode and set to [use the same channel](http://flashhavoc.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/YN_560_III_Channels_a400.jpg) as your RF-600TX, they should communicate with each other.

Comment: There are illustrations to go along with cursory instructions on how to set the YN-560 III to RF-602 mode and how to set the channel selector to match the dip switches on the RF-600TX in [this article at Flash Havoc](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn-560-iii-review/comment-page-1/). The YN-560 IV should be pretty much the same.

Comment: @MichaelClark Thanks. Have updated with links to the FH graphics.